# Show the value, not the vector name in cat funciton print out

Tags: cat

This is using Rstudio. I have this line without syntax erro

cat("The\tdistance\tbetween\tthe\tstations\nthis\r5\tand\t7\nthis\ris\tresult")

It prints out below
The distance    between the stations
5   and 7
is  result

Two questions:
1. how to delete extra blank spaces between the words? I like to compress to 1
2. Result actually is the name of a vector. it has value =2.5. I want to show this value of 2.5, the name of the vector Result. Thanks

Comment: Should be "I want to show this value of 2.5, Not the name of the vector Result. " Thanks

Comment: I figured the 2 by doing this cat("The\tdistance\tbetween\tthe\tstations\nt\r5\tand\t7\nt\ris",result). Now, how to compress the excessive space on the top two lines?  The last line looks fine now.